# Photoshop resize circularly

Tags: photoshop, image-resizing

Is there a way to do this circular resize of a pattern in photoshop (flat image) ?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking a programming question or a photoshop feature question. If the second your question probably belongs on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know the website indeed, I posted it there
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137920/photoshop-resize-circularly